# Completing or inserting empty rows in-between ordered factors

Tags: r

I have a data frame where I have aggregated the total activity per member for 15 different months (as ordered factors). Now the months/levels, where a member has not had any activity is simply skipped as there are no rows in the original data.

The data looks like this:

```
MemberID  MonthYr  freq 
1         04-2014    2
1         05-2014    3
1         07-2014    2
1         08-2014    5
2         04-2014    3
2         05-2014    3
3         06-2014    6
3         07-2014    4
3         11-2014    2
3         12-2014    3
```

I want to insert new rows in between the active months, so that the months show a frequency of 0.

Like this:

```
MemberID  MonthYr  freq 
1         04-2014    2
1         05-2014    3
1         06-2014    0
1         07-2014    2
1         08-2014    5
2         04-2014    3
2         05-2014    3
3         06-2014    6
3         07-2014    4
3         08-2014    0
3         09-2014    0
3         10-2014    0
3         11-2014    2
3         12-2014    3
```

However every member hasn't become members at the same time, so the 0's can only be between the min and max `MonthYr` for each member.

Comment: I've had several issues with converting the class to as.date earlier. And I get the error:  Error in complete(., MonthYr = seq(min(MonthYr), max(MonthYr),  : 
  'data' not of class 'mids'

Comment: The comment wouldn't work because we are  applynig `seq` on the yearmon,  Please check my updated solution posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `complete` to do this.  Convert the 'MonthYr' to `Date` class, then grouped by 'MemberID', use `complete` to expand the 'MonthYr' from `min` to `max` 'Date' `by` 'month', while `fill`ing  the 'freq' with 0 and if needed, convert back the 'MonthYr' to original `format`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(MonthYr = as.Date(as.yearmon(MonthYr, "%m-%Y"))) %>% 
   group_by(MemberID) %>% 
   complete(MonthYr = seq(min(MonthYr), max(MonthYr), by = '1 month'), 
      fill = list(freq = 0)) %>% 
   mutate(MonthYr = format(MonthYr, "%m-%Y"))
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   MemberID [3]
#   MemberID MonthYr  freq
#      <int> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1        1 04-2014     2
# 2        1 05-2014     3
# 3        1 06-2014     0
# 4        1 07-2014     2
# 5        1 08-2014     5
# 6        2 04-2014     3
# 7        2 05-2014     3
# 8        3 06-2014     6
# 9        3 07-2014     4
#10        3 08-2014     0
#11        3 09-2014     0
#12        3 10-2014     0
#13        3 11-2014     2
#14        3 12-2014     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(MemberID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), MonthYr = c("04-2014", "05-2014", "07-2014", "08-2014", 
"04-2014", "05-2014", "06-2014", "07-2014", "11-2014", "12-2014"
), freq = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: I still get the same error: 'data' not of class 'mids' . I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @amandr can you update your post with the `dput(yourexample)`  It seems like your data have some attributes

Comment: It seems like I've had problems because I have several packages loaded, and some overwrite the others. I fixed this by using :: in the code to specify what package that related to that line of code.  I ended up creating a new column for tenure by months, and used this code to add rows where there was a gap in the tenure.    group_by(MemberID) %>%
  tidyr::complete(TenureMonths = full_seq(TenureMonths, 1), fill = list(freq = 0, Churn =0))